# Count same fields from different arrays

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have this form, and the results are written to a csv file (`inschrijvingen.csv`) and it looks like this:

```
Person,City,Email,NumberOfP1,NumberOfP2,NumberOfP3,Total
```

which I then read out with

```
 <?php
 $rowcount = 0;
 $file = fopen('inschrijvingen.csv', "r");
 while (($artext = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
 $line = ++$rowcount;
 $naam = $artext[0];
 $city = $artext[1];
 $email = $artext[2];
 $adce = $artext[3];
 $adc = $artext[4];
 $che = $artext[5];
 $sum = $artext[6];
 print_r($artext);
 }
 fclose($file);

 ?>
```

This gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => Person1 [1] => City [2] => person1@outlook.com [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [5] => 0 [6] => 15 ) 
Array ( [0] => Person2 [1] => City [2] => person2@outlook.com [3] => 0 [4] => 3 [5] => 0 [6] => 45 ) 
Array ( [0] => Person3 [1] => City [2] => person3@outlook.com [3] => 1 [4] => 2 [5] => 2 [6] => 71 )
```

That is good, it's correct, and I can display this all in a table.
But now I would need the sum of every value in `$artext[3]` , `$artext[4]` , `$artext[5]` but since it's multiple arrays I can't really process them.
I tried putting all the needed values in a different array of their own, but that didn't work.

So now I would like to know how I can count my values, so I have a total per product.

(In this example: `$artext[3]` sum = 1 , `$artext[4]` sum = 6 , `$artext[5]` sum = 2 )

To be clear: `$sum = $artext[6];` contains the total price, as calculated by the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
 $rowcount = 0;

 $adceSum = 0;
 $adcSum = 0;
 $cheSum = 0;

 $file = fopen('inschrijvingen.csv', "r");
 while (($artext = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
 $line = ++$rowcount;
 $naam = $artext[0];
 $city = $artext[1];
 $email = $artext[2];
 $adce = $artext[3];
 $adc = $artext[4];
 $che = $artext[5];
 $sum = $artext[6];
 print_r($artext);

 $adceSum += $adce;
 $adcSum += $adc;
 $cheSum += $che;
 }

 // Here you have the sum in $adceSum, $adcSum and $cheSum.
 fclose($file);
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was so simple. (I feel really stupid now, but will never forget this). I tried something similar, but in the wrong way apparently. Thank you very much.

Comment: Some times everyone get stuck ;) Just mark the answer as "Correct" so people know your problem is solved.

Comment: Done, I was waiting until the waiting time was over :)